# Count number of descendants in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a table of objects with ID's, some of them are based on other objects.
For this I use a field called path, which lists the string of parents' IDs

Object D (path="A,B,C") is based on object C which is based on B which is based on A.

Now I want to select * from all objects, plus an extra column: count(descendants)
(A has 3 (B,C and D) B has 2 (C and D) and C has just one (D) - D has zero

"my" descendants are the number of objects whose path = myPath+myID(+more?)
- Is this possible in SQL only (without looping in PHP) ?

O id=a .... path="" .......... a has 5 descendants
O id=b .... path="a" ........ b has 3
O id=c .... path="a,b" .....  c has 1
O id=d .... path="a,b,c" ..  d has 0
O id=n .... path="a,b" .....  n has 0
O id=x .... path="a" ........ x has 0

Comment: Check out [Heirarchical Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to extrapolate the number of descendants based on the longest chain, or for example does `Object C` in the table already have `D` as its `path` value?  If I understand it, it would be already quite difficult if the `path` is present for all rows, owing to the multi-value column. But if those are not filled in all the way up the chain, it will be ludicrously hard to do in SQL.

Comment: Post a sample of rows from the table to remove ambiguity, please.

Comment: They are filled in - all forebears are lined up in order in the path-field (string)

Comment: Given the sample you just included, I think I misunderstand still. By my reading, `a` should have 5 descendants rather than 4 because b,c,d,n,x all have a* in their paths. Is that a mistake?

Comment: If you are really storing this tree-like hierarchy in your DB as path "a,b,c," and similar you are going to be in a world of hurt when you try to do anything other than most basic queries against that hierarchy.  You probably need to rethink your table structure.  Check out this link for some suggestions, with pros and cons of each - http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  MySQL is especially poor amongst relational databases with regards to storing tree-like hierarchies, to the point where you may want to consider alternate technologies.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - You're right 5 from a

Comment: @Mike Brant: Oops, I'm trying to make it simple(!) hierarchies never change after creation - but can go very deep: 20-30 levels... Anyway thanks for the educational link - maybe the stack of LEFT JOINs isn't as hard as it looks  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This table structure is likely to become problematic if you need to query it frequently. It is seldom recommended to store multiple values in a single column, though MySQL has a rudimentary method of reading inside them.

Given your existing requirements though, the query turns out not to be that difficult to produce the result you want. Using a `LEFT JOIN` to join the table against *itself* with a different alias, you may use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()` string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to locate the `object` inside the `path` as a joining condition.

Following the join, you can `COUNT()` the matches from `FIND_IN_SET()`, and since you used a `LEFT JOIN`, it will return `0` for those with no descendants.

```
SELECT
  o.*,
  -- Count matches from the joined table
  COUNT(odesc.object) AS num_descendants
FROM
  paths o
  -- Self join with FIND_IN_SET()
  LEFT JOIN paths odesc ON FIND_IN_SET(o.object, odesc.path)
GROUP BY o.object
```

And given your sample rows, here is a demo if it working and producing your expected result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fae7/1

Now, if your data is not as regular as your sample, that may still allow for paths that don't follow exactly, and instead merely just have the object as a member. Adding an additional `LIKE` condition can enforce that the paths on both sides of the `LEFT JOIN` start the same way, which means one path extends the other.

```
 LEFT JOIN paths odesc ON
   FIND_IN_SET(o.object, odesc.path)
   -- Additional condition to ensure paths start the same
   AND odesc.path LIKE CONCAT(COALESCE(o.path, ''), '%')
```

And just to verify the result is the same, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fae7/15

Note, that using `FIND_IN_SET()` will never be fast. That's what makes this difficult -- MySQL doesn't have good native functionality for splitting up a string, and won't be able to utilize an index well.

#### Addendum:

I ran the `EXPLAIN` against the `FIND_IN_SET()` query, with an index on each of the two columns:

```
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | o     | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ox    | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here's the explain of the dependent subquery from the comments, after correcting the source data to use trailing commas and empty strings instead of `NULL`:

```
EXPLAIN select    paths.*,   (select count(object)     from paths ox    where LEFT(ox.path,char_length( concat( paths.path, paths.object))) = concat(paths.path, paths.object ) )as descendants from paths;
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | paths | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using index              |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ox    | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index |
+------+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

And finally, the modified data with the subselect expressed instead as a `LEFT JOIN`, which MySQL may be better able to optimize:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
   paths.*,
   COUNT(ox.object)
FROM
  paths
  LEFT JOIN paths ox
     ON LEFT(ox.path,char_length(concat(paths.path, paths.object))) = concat(paths.path, paths.object)
GROUP BY paths.object;

+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | paths | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | ox    | index | NULL          | path | 20      | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

All three appear to be able to use an index, but you will  need to benchmkark them against a real rowset to find which is the most efficient. Importantly, these were run against a very recent MariaDB version. If you have an older MySQL, your results may vary widely.

I find modifying the original data to meet a requirement of trailing commas somewhat distasteful.

Comment: Awesome - with the FIND_IN_SET even a tree with holes in it would work (AND multiple lines of parents... surely an abomination)...  But if it's slow... Couldn't I count objects whose paths match exactly myPath+","+myID.. using SUBSTRING and CHAR_LENGTH (more primitive, but faster?)

Comment: @T4NK3R Any of those string operations are probably not going to be much faster than `FIND_IN_SET()`, if at all, unless it can be done strictly with left-anchored comparisons so an index could be used. I've got to run right now, but if I think of a solution (2 or 3 I've tried have not worked), I'll edit to add it later.

Comment: The more I think on it, the more complex it becomes to avoid FIND_IN_SET() - because you need special `CASE` handling for empty paths and commas, etc.

Comment: I can't get the fiddle to work with your left join and group by... but this match looks more index-friendly to me: left( ox.path, char_length(concat(o.path,o.object))) = concat(o.path,o.object)

Comment: That won't quite work because the concatenation results in values like `A,X`, which never exist when the full path from A....X isn't present. As long as there are instances like `X` or `N` in your sample where the path is not an exact build-up of all that came before, I don't think you'll be able to rely on substrings. I made many attempts using a wildcard LIKE, CONCAT(), and SUBSTR(), but those rows always cause incorrect results.  I have a couple more things to try with a wildcard LIKE...

Comment: It would work (with `LEFT(...CHAR_LENGTH())` or `LIKE CONCAT(object, '%')` it appears, only for `A`'s descendants. To find `B` descendants for example, you will always have to look in the middle of the string, necessitating either FIND_IN_SET() or `LIKE '%xxx%'` with _both_ wildcards. Of those, `FIND_IN_SET()` avoids all the extra overhead then to add/remove/parse commas to create a legitimate LIKE query.  The other concatenations all have those same problems, but also, using the two `CONCAT()` won't be able to use an index either. The concat will have to be applied before `LEFT()` ...cont'd.

Comment: No. To find Bs descendants, you look for Bs path + ",B"  ("A,B") - so LEFT should work, I just make my fat fingers write it right :(

Comment: Got it! the empty path must be an empty string (not null) - and the non-empty paths must end in an extra komma. Then this (messy) select works (in your fiddle):   select paths.*, 
          (select count(object) 
           from paths ox 
           where LEFT(ox.path,char_length( concat( paths.path, paths.object))) = concat(paths.path, paths.object )
          )as descendants
        from paths

Comment: So you've ultimately traded the FIND_IN_SET() for a subselect, which MySQL has terrible optimization for, and is likely to be far slower. I did you run an EXPLAIN against that query (after changing the data to add the trailing commas) and it won't use an index on paths.  I strongly suggest you benchmark both with real data because I'm not confident you're going to get performance out of the contorted subselect and concatenation.

Comment: @T4NK3R I added the execution plans from MariaDB for three variations on this query.

Comment: My introduction of a subselect was only caused by my being unable to make the left join work (SQL novice). I've learned a lot from you. (and gotten new exciting ideas by the introduction of find_in_set()).. Thank you.

Comment: @T4NK3R Glad to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a table with column keyy for the id and parents with parents. I also assume that every parent in the parents column is terminated by ",".
Then:

```
select t.*, 
      (select count(*) 
       from t tt 
       where tt.parents between concat( t.parents , t.keyy ,',' )
         and  concat(t.parents , t.keyy ,',zzzzzzzzzz' ) )as descendants
    from t
```

If you have an index on the column parents then it can be used. 
Maybe you should replace the zz withs something more reasonable.

See:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2d5e/1

Comment: Works too. As does this (apparently?)   WHERE LEFT(tt.parents,char_length(concat( t.parents , t.keyy))) = concat( t.parents , t.keyy) - a single match (with index-freindly LEFT)

Comment: This actually won't work for the case of `X` with the path `A`. It won't be recognized as a descendant of `A`.

Comment: And the LEFT(CHAR_INDEX()) version will return an incorrect value for `c` in that test set, 2 descendants instead of 1. These methods can only work with completely contiguous paths `A,B,C,D....N....X`

Comment: In Rolans's data X isn't a descendant of A. X stands alone beside A: For his data this LEFTY-version works:  select t.*, 
          (select count(*) 
           from t tt 
           where LEFT(tt.parents,char_length(concat( t.parents , t.keyy, ","))) = concat( t.parents , t.keyy,",")
          )as descendants
        from t

Comment: The extra komma above is only needed to distinguish between C and C2  - if all IDs were the same length it wouldn't be necessary